# .rangeChart dc.js equivalent in d3 version 4

Tags: reactjs, dc.js, d3.js

Using dc.js. Is there a change of the syntax/naming for the .rangeChart() in d3 version 4 ? Can't find anything in the documentation.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is planned, but dc.js does not yet support d3 version 4 - see https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1173

Comment: Could anyone please verify this to me - .rangeChart()  is a dc feature not a d3 feature ?

Comment: Yep, [that's right](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.coordinateGridMixin+rangeChart). d3 is just low-level drawing, interaction, and layout stuff - it doesn't actually contain any charts.